# Vite Server / HMR for Chrome Extension Development

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vite

I have a `vite` `vue 3` project set up to build a chrome extension.

It creates the `manifest.json`, copies that and some static assets and builds the whole thing to a dist folder - from where you can run the extension locally.

And any changes to files will trigger a re build.

But that is very slow compared to the `vite` server with `HMR`.

I have tried many ways to get some level of HMR  - but cant get it to work.

Is this possible?

The closest I got was running `vite build` first, then running the server, and having the `base` property set to the localhost server.

```js
base: 'http://localhost:3303',
server: {
  port: 3303,
  hmr: {
    host: 'localhost'
  }
},
```

However, chrome `CSP` blocks this even with the correct permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have HMR, while using vite and vue3, while developing an extension, but not sure if it is possible out of the box.

I am using vue 3/ vite and tailwind with [crxjs](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin/getting-started/vue/create-project) (vite plugin for chrome extensions) and it works pretty much seamlessly.

Comment: Hi @Zarko are you able to get HMR while using Tailwind CSS along with CRXJS? I'm able to add it, but I need to restart the dev server for the new tailwind classes to be reflected

Comment: @pbsh Yes, I'm able to do that. If you add tailwind for the first time - you need to restart the server, but if you just update/add new classes not sure if you have to restart it. Check vite/tailwind config on that matter though.

Comment: Currently, CRXJS plugin has an issue with hot reloading Tailwind classes in content scripts, you have to reload the dev server after each update in your code.

Comment: There is a workaround for this issue. Learn more here - https://github.com/crxjs/chrome-extension-tools/issues/671